# Is 'watching him' a gerund clause in this example?

Tags: complements, participle-clauses, gerund-clauses, catenative-verbs

> He saw James watching him.

Recently, I have become familiar with non-finite clauses. This has led me to question the function of the ing- clause in constructions like the one above. Prior to learning about non-finite clauses, I would have said that 'watching him' is a participle phrase (now I know it's a clause). However, I am wondering if 'watching him' is in fact a gerund clause.

It could be argued that 'watching him' describes James, whom 'he' saw. But it could also be argued that 'he' saw the act of 'watching him', which just so happens to be performed by James. Therefore, I would deduce that it is a catenative complement of 'saw'.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, it's a catenative construction. "See" is a catenative verb and "watching him" is a subordinate gerund-participial clause functioning as its catenative complement. "James" is the syntactic object of "see" and the understood (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *He saw James watching him.*

Yes, it's a catenative construction.

"See" is a catenative verb and "watching him" is a subordinate gerund-participial clause functioning as its catenative complement.

"James" is the syntactic object of "see" and the *understood* (semantic) subject of the subordinate clause.

Note that "James" is here called a 'raised object': the verb it relates to syntactically is higher in the constituent structure than the one it relates to semantically.

Answer (score 0):

The structure "saw + object + -ing" is used to emphasise the action in progress (watching).

He saw James + James was watching him = He saw James watching him.

According to Cambridge English Grammar Today,

> We can use either the infinitive without to or the -ing form after the
> object of verbs such as hear, see, notice, watch. The infinitive
> without to often emphasises the whole action or event which someone
> hears or sees. The -ing form usually emphasises an action or event
> which is in progress or not yet completed.
>
> - He saw her drive off with a young man in the passenger seat. (The speaker observed the whole event.)
> - Maria heard him coming up the stairs towards her room, and felt scared. (The action was in progress, happening, but not completed.)